# AG-Grid upgrade from 27 to 28 import errors - Angular

Tags: ag-grid, upgrade, ag-grid-angular

I try to upgrade from AG-Grid 27 modules

```
"@ag-grid-community/angular": "^27.0.0",
"@ag-grid-enterprise/all-modules": "^27.0.0",
```

to 28.2 packages

```
"ag-grid-angular": "^28.2.0",
"ag-grid-community": "^28.2.0",
"ag-grid-enterprise": "^28.2.0",
```

(Based on the ag-grid documentation packages has everything you need, you don't need to install modules like above see v 27.0.0)

```
foo.ts - v27.0.0 - @ag-grid-enterprise/all-modules
import {
!NO IMPORT ERRORS!
} from '@ag-grid-enterprise/all-modules';
```

But I still have import errors:

```
foo.ts - v28.2.0 - ag-grid-enterprise
import {
BodyScrollEvent, < Module '"ag-grid-enterprise"' has no exported member 'BodyScrollEvent'.
CellKeyPressEvent, < Module '"ag-grid-enterprise"' has no exported member 'CellKeyPressEvent'.
CellValueChangedEvent,  < Module '"ag-grid-enterprise"' has no exported member 'CellValueChangedEvent'
CheckboxSelectionCallback,
ColDef,
Column,
ColumnApi,
...
} from 'ag-grid-enterprise';
```

What did I wrongly, if the packages has everything ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use BodyScrollEvent but the CellValueChangedEvent and CellKeyPressEvent are now in ag-grid-community.
Please could you try

```
import { CellValueChangedEvent, CellKeyPressEvent } from 'ag-grid-community';
```

If that works, it might be the same with BodyScrollEvent as well

Comment: After some time (one day:( ), I realized too, yes the events have been moved to ag-grid-community